# Associate android developer certification

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I have few questions for any one who have taken this certification from google.

1. what kind of design pattern does the project follow MVP, MVVM.
2. Can i use room persistence library for all the sqlite task or should i carve out raw sql queries.
3. Does the project use Data binding.﻿

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have cleared the `Associate android developer certification` last December. For test you will be given a source code with missing pieces and you have to fill those missing gaps in that code to make it fully functional. Main point to be noted here is that after you submit the code they use automation tools to test the same. So it is instructed not to rename any package, change any structure or rename the provided classes or variables.

1. As far as i remember, it was a very basic or simple architecture (Sort of `Mvp` and `Mvc`) very easy to understand. So from developer point of view, the base architecture will already be there, you don't need to worry about that.
2. Knowledge of `Content Provider` is must. As i mentioned the whole code is already written with missing pieces. So you can't use room or any other library for `sqlite`.
3. It doesn't uses `Data binding`

You can go through the following link (Exam content section) to check all the required skills for the exams in details.
https://developers.google.com/training/certification/associate-android-developer/

Hope this information helps you

Comment: Yep, you cleared most of the part and one last thing is does the project have like baseview and basepresenter from which we define view and presenter interfaces like in MVP or is the project just laid out in different packages like data package for sqlite, network package for api calls, ui package for views, etc.

Comment: It's just laid out  in different packages like 'data', 'widget' etc

Comment: @Nitesh  Can we google anything while giving test ?

Comment: Hi @Vikas, This is quite an old answer and the format/content for exam must have changed. Please don't rely on the suggestions given in this answer.

Comment: About google search, as far as I remember, we could do that 5 years back.. but again my knowledge is years old and outdated about this topic.